# XML Schema: Cannot find the declaration of element 'users'

Tags: xml, xsd

I am new to XML Schema. So I really dont know what happened. I followed the tutorials and created an valid XML Schema. But it cant find the declaration. That's odd.

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<users>
<user><id>1</id><username>thomas01</username><display_name>Thomas Müntzer</display_name><birthday>04.12.1956</birthday><email_address>thomas@muentzer.de</email_address><quota>524288000</quota><quota_used>14727606</quota_used></user>
</users>
```

The XML Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.infbox_normal.com" xmlns="http://www.infbox_normal.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="users">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="user">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:integer"/>
                            <xs:element name="username" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="display_name" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="birthday" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="email_address">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:pattern value="/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="quote" type="xs:integer"/>
                            <xs:element name="quote_used" type="xs:integer"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    </xs:schema>
```

The error meg:

`Error - Line 2, 8: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 8; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'users'.`

I use [this](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation) to validate the XML Schema.

Comment: Your XSD lacks a root "schema" element.

Comment: @svinja Was only bad formatting, the element was there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSD defines a target namespace `http://www.infbox_normal.com` but your XML has no namespaces.

Comment: But I find a related question. How can you explain that in that example the same test can be passed?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949846/xml-validation-against-xsd-in-php-libxml  In that example there is no namespace in that validated xml file.

Comment: @JACKM And there's also no `targetNamespace` in the schema.

Comment: Look at the webpage I gave you in the first comment. And then paste and copy the xml file and the xml schema to http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation. The xml file does not have any namespace info. But the validation can be passed.

Comment: Oh, yes you are right. Thank you. I am really confused about some concepts.